# Multithreading in WinRT C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to simply create a new thread and run another instance of DispatcherTimer on it. Don't want it to run on the GUI thread because I can't get the event happen more often than once per 16 ms (it's because the app runs at 60 FPS). Is using ThreadPool the best way to do that? I don't really know anything about threading in WinRT Windows Store apps, and I couldn't find anything interesting. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to have only one thread, then it doesn't really matter what you use - it's all more or less the same, no matter if it's called Task, Thread or BackgroundWorker.

Much more important: You can use the DispatcherTimer only on a Dispatcher thread, so you need to find something else. E.g. the ThreadPoolTimer or something homebrown with ResetEvent.Wait or Task.Delay. 
However if you want to update the UI from this thread, then you need to call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke which won't work more often that once per 16ms anyway ...

```
void TestDispatcherTimer()
{
    // need to create and start DispatcherTimer on UI thread, because ...
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5);
    dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
    dt.Start();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ... if uncommented, each single line crashes because of wrong thread
        // DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer(); 
        // dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5); 
        // dt.Tick += dt_Tick; 
        // dt.Start(); 
    });
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    int id = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId; // id will always be the UI thread's id
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tick on thread " + id + ": " + now.Minute + ":" + now.Second + "." + now.Millisecond);
}

void TestThreadpoolTimer()
{
    // it doesn't matter if the ThreadPoolTimer is created on UI thread or any other thread
    ThreadPoolTimer tpt = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(tpt_Tick, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));
}

void tpt_Tick(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    int id = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId; // id will change, but never be the UI thread's id
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tick on thread " + id + ": " + now.Minute + ":" + now.Second + "." + now.Millisecond);
}
```

Comment: I want to have separate thread for GUI and logic. I thought it's possible to run DispatcherTimer on a non-GUI thread, then I'd be able to set the interval to less than 16 ms, do some work every tick, and then I'd check the result in the GUI thread periodically. Is it really impossible?

Comment: I added two samples: TestDispatcherTimer will only run if the timer is created on the UI thread (Task.Run spawns a new non-UI thread) and the events are always raised on the UI thread. In contrast TestThreadpoolTimer raises the events on a new thread each.

Comment: Is it possible to create only ONE thread that would do some repeating job, but wihtout starting another job until the previous one has finished? But I don't want to use DispatcherTimer, because it spoils the GUI (some lags etc.). ThreadPoolTimer starts a new thread every time it calls the delegate, so new jobs start before the previous ones have finished.

Comment: Yes, possible. Fur running and enqueuing multiple jobs on one single thread you might look up "job queue" or "message queue". The much simpler solution is to synchronize the jobs (which run on one thread each) by using a SynchronizationContext or (even simpler) a Semaphore.

Comment: Woulnd't it be the easiest to use 'lock' statement? I have one method that gets called every 256 ms, I want to make sure it finished before it gets called again.

Comment: Ooops. Yes, you're right. A lock should do it. Sorry.